# Ошибка class java.lang.RuntimeException при создании Destination Resource в glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

Я создал очередь `TestQueue` в MOM Open MQ и протестировал работу с ней, создав 2 класса:

```
import javax.jms.*;
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory;
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration;

public class MessageSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session  = null;
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        QueueConnection connection = null;
        try{
            factory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, "mq://localhost:7677,mq://localhost:7677");

            connection = factory.createQueueConnection("admin","admin");
            connection.start();

            session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue ioQueue = session.createQueue("TestQueue");
            MessageProducer queueSender = session.createProducer(ioQueue);
            TextMessage outText = session.createTextMessage("MS 1000 Mkt");
            queueSender.send(outText);
            queueSender.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully placed an order to purchase 200 shares of IBM");

        }catch(JMSException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try{
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(Exception e1){
                System.out.println("Can't close JMS session/connection " + e1.getMessage());
            }
        }



    }

}
```

и второй:

```
import javax.jms.*;

import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory;
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration;

public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener{

    Session session = null;
    ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    QueueConnection connection;
    MessageConsumer consumer;

    MessageReceiver(){
        try{
            //Специфично для mq
            factory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList,
                    "mq://localhost:7677,mq://localhost:7677");
            connection = factory.createQueueConnection("admin","admin");
            connection.start();

            session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue ioQueue = session.createQueue("TestQueue");
            consumer = session.createConsumer(ioQueue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(this);

            System.out.println("Listening to the TestQueue");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ie.getMessage());
        }catch(JMSException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try{
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Can't close JMS session/connection " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MessageReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String msgText;
        try{
            if(msg instanceof TextMessage){
                msgText = ((TextMessage)msg).getText();
                System.out.println("Got from the queue: " + msgText);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Got a non-text message");
            }

        }catch(JMSException e){
            System.out.println("Eror while consuming a message " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь я хочу использовать JNDI в своей программе, привязав JNDI к моей очереди, но при создании Destination Resource выдает ошибку.

Я думаю проблема в том, что glassfish "не видит" очередь созданную в Open MQ: в административной консоли glassfish  во вкладке Java Message Service нет никаких Physical Destinations, которые должны там быть, поскольку я создал очередь в Open MQ, и по идее glassfish должен сам уже знать о них (так как Open MQ встроен в glassfish).

Отсюда и ошибка `NullPointerException`, поскольку при создании Destination Resource нужно обязательно указать Physical Destinations, а их нет.

Полный код ошибки:

```
[2015-10-21T17:18:28.393+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=187 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1445437108393] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event247'.
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:551)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.handlers.UtilHandlers.mapPut(UtilHandlers.java:314)
    ... 51 more
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы glassfish "увидел" очередь, созданную в Open MQ?

Comment: NullPointerException - где то ты что-то не объявил